# How to set serializer to an internal class extending a public interface?

Tags: kotlin, serialization, kotlinx.serialization, compose-desktop

I'm trying to create a serializer using `kotlinx.serialization` for `Compose Desktop` classes, I have this :

```kotlin
@Serializer(forClass = MutableState::class)
class MutableStateSerializer<T>(private val dataSerializer: KSerializer<T>) : KSerializer<MutableState<T>> {
    override fun deserialize(decoder: Decoder) = mutableStateOf(decoder.decodeSerializableValue(dataSerializer))
    override val descriptor: SerialDescriptor = dataSerializer.descriptor
    override fun serialize(encoder: Encoder, value: MutableState<T>) = encoder.encodeSerializableValue(dataSerializer, value.value)
}
```

That should be used for instances of `MutableState` class (as the `@Serializer` annotation says), but I have to put an explicit serializer for each properties otherwise I get this error :

```kotlin
xception in thread "main" kotlinx.serialization.SerializationException: Class 'SnapshotMutableStateImpl' is not registered for polymorphic serialization in the scope of 'MutableState'.
Mark the base class as 'sealed' or register the serializer explicitly
```

Code used :

```kotlin
@Serializable
class Test {
    var number = mutableStateOf(0)
}

fun main() {
   val json = Json { prettyPrint = true }
   val serialized = json.encodeToString(Test())
   println(serialized)
}
```

I have to put this annotation on my property :

```kotlin
@Serializable(with = MutableStateSerializer::class)
```

Isn't there a way to automatically link my serializer to the `MutableState` interface ? As the `SnapshotMutableStateImpl` is internal I can't set it to this class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is currently not possible. Other people seem to have requested a feature similar to what you need on GitHub: [Global Custom Serializers](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization/issues/507).

Currently, for [3rd party classes, you need to specify the serializer](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization/blob/master/docs/serializers.md#serializing-3rd-party-classes) in one of three ways:

- Pass the custom serializer to the encode/decode method in case you are serializing it as the root object.
- Specify the serializer on the property using `@Serializable`, as you do now.
- Specify the serializer to be used by a full file using `@file:UseSerializers`.

Note that due to type inference, `number` will be attempted to be serialized as the return type of `mutableStateOf`. If you specify the type as an interface instead (does it have a supertype?), using polymorphic serialization, you could try to register the concrete type and pass your custom serializer there for the concrete type. Not really what this feature is designed for, but I believe it may work if you don't want to specify your serializer in multiple places. However, the serialized form will then include a type discriminator everywhere.

Comment: If I use the `@file:UserSerializers` annotation, do I have to put **all** the serializers I need ? Like `String`, `Number` etc. ? Or do I only have to do this for my custom serializers ?